# SQL Updating and Inserting dupcliate tables with linked server

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-update

SQL Server 2012 (local) to SQL Server 2005 (Linked)

I need to keep the (linked) server in sync with the local server which includes about 2-3 tables only (not the whole database).  This is not really time sensitive so I don't want to use triggers and such.  We just want to have this run 1-2 times per day as a scheduled task.

I have tried:

DELETE FROM linked_server

INSERT INTO linked_server
(value1,value2,value3)
SELECT value1,value2,value3) FROM local_server

But the process is taking like 45 minutes plus to run.  I would like to do something more quickly - I have searched and searched but really can't find any good solution (that is in my level of understanding).

Typically we're talking only 30 records or so are either updated or inserted.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Well I have no idea how moving 30 records could possibly take 45 minutes - is the query blocked by something during this time?

Comment: I am deleting the linked_server table records first then re-inserting all the records ... which is what I want to avoid - need to either update or insert records based on changes.

Comment: I understand. That still shouldn't take 45 minutes (or any minutes, for that matter).

Comment: I originally thought that .. but it's inserting 20,000 - 40,000 records remotely so maybe? for each table (4 - 5 tables)

Comment: then why does your question talk about "30 records"?

Comment: because typically there are only about 30 records that are changed or needed to be added ... but I am ripping them all out and inserting all back in .. figured there is a better way.

Comment: Ok, that makes a little more sense, but it's certainly not clear in the question.

Comment: Wouldn't Openquery be for bring data from the remote back to the local instead of from local to remote?

Comment: I deleted my comment about using the Openquery for deletes and Inserts becuase 'm not 100% sure. @Aaron: Can you please shed some light, if we can perform Deletes and Inserts through openquery.

Comment: @Sonam I'm not sure why you would want to... how would `OPENQUERY` improve the situation?

Comment: This is what I know about openquery: Openquery connects to the destination server and runs the query on that server and returns the resultset. Whereas, in case of linked server query is executed on the local server.

Comment: @Sonam it depends (you can also use remote join hints to force it). I'm not convinced that the problem here is as straightforward as you suggest (e.g. it will suddenly be magically fast with `OPENQUERY`), but I guess it can't hurt to try. From my personal experience I've dealt with a lot of linked server issues and that was never a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems like the key is you don't care how old the data is (or you'd want to do this more than 1-2 times a day), but you want minimal disruption to users who are reading the data.

Now, since you are going down-level from 2012 to 2005, some obvious choices are going to be problematic/impossible, such as replication. And doing some sort of MERGE operation (e.g. using a ROWVERSION to detect changes between the two sources, if you even have a ROWVERSION column now) could still be cumbersome, inefficient and might still disrupt users trying to read the data on the other end.

The easiest way IMHO would be to have a shadow copy of the table... you truncate that, populate it with all of the data (regardless of how long that takes - again, this part shouldn't matter, since it's happening in the background), then swap it out for the real table as a metadata operation. Basically you ave two extra schemas (`shadow` and `fake`), create identical copies of your tables in the `shadow` schema, and then perform an operation like this (probably best to have this run on the 2005 server and pull, rather than push form 2012, so you don't have to worry about distributed transactions etc):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE shadow.tablename;

INSERT shadow.tablename([cols]) 
  SELECT [cols] FROM SQL2012.db.dbo.tablename;

-- perhaps an explicit statistics update here

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  -- this metadata operation is fast and it's the only
  -- block/blockee in this operation.
  ALTER SCHEMA fake TRANSFER     dbo.tablename;
  ALTER SCHEMA dbo  TRANSFER  shadow.tablename;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

ALTER SCHEMA shadow TRANSFER fake.tablename;
```

(Even better would be to have a stored procedure on the SQL Server 2012 side, so you could `INSERT...EXEC` and have more control over isolation level - e.g. set that up with RCSI or *shudder* `NOLOCK`.)

I blogged about this here:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo

Comment: I am using this answer because we're already doing something similar to the shadow table .. but some of the information in your blog gave me the correct answer that I am looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there are more lines in the tables than the 30 records you update or insert every day. 
If you have a timestamp/rowversion column in your source table and a primary key you could save the timestamp value in your linked server and then update all values in the linked server where

```
local.primary=linked.primary and local.timestamp!=linked.stamp
```

and then insert only the new rows by selecting primary keys that don't exist on linked server.